# Refresh asp controls periodically

Tags: asp.net, refresh, global-asax

I have an aspx web form in a WCF service project that gives a status report on that service. Currently I have a Refresh button, but I'd like to automate a regular periodic refresh.

I've tried two ways:

1. A javascript inside `<head>` using `setInterval()` and started in `Page_Load` with `RegisterStartupScript`.
2. A `Systems.Timers.Timer` inside `Page_Load`, doing what the button click would do.

I don't get (1) right because of an obvious scope problem and I'm clearly misunderstanding how it should work. Currently the script simply does an alert, and I can't get further.

I don't get (2) right, though it seems as if it should work, because putting a breakpoint into the timer function shows correct values, but the form labels on the page don't update.

The webform.aspx looks as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Manage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyServiceWS.ManageForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Manage</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // method (1)
        RefreshScript = function ()
        {
            setInterval(function () { alert("How to call the Refresh code?"); }, 5000);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <p>
                Synchronisation status: 
                <asp:Label ID="SyncStatusLabel" runat="server" />
                <p>
                <asp:Button ID="RefreshButton" runat="server" Text="Refresh" 
                    onclick="RefreshButton_Click" />
                <p>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The c# code in the webform.aspx.cs looks as follows. This is where the desired refresh code resides. Of course I only try one method at a time, they're both uncommented below for clarity as to what I've been trying.

```
namespace MyServiceWS
{
    public partial class ManageForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // method (1)
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "addScript", "RefreshScript()", true);

            if (Page.IsPostBack)
                Refresh();
            else
            { // method (2)
                var myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimedRefreshEvent);
                myTimer.Interval = 5000;
                myTimer.Start();
            }
        }
        protected void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Refresh();
        }

        private void TimedRefreshEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Refresh();
        }

        private void Refresh()
        {
            SyncStatusLabel.Text = Global.StatusDescription;
        }
    }
}
```

A `Global.asax` file contains the static string variable `StatusDescription` which correctly contains a status that is populated elsewhere by the service.

I'm stumped, are either methods correct, and how do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
RefreshScript = function () 
        { 
            setInterval(function () { alert("How to call the Refresh code?"); }, 5000); 
        }
```

To:

```
function RefreshScript()
{ 
     setInterval(function () { alert("How to call the Refresh code?"); }, 5000); 
}
```

And see if that works better.

You can also use the timer approach, but not through System.Timers.Timer; use the [ASP.NET AJAX timer control](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/IntroToTimerControl.aspx).

Comment: The AJAX timer method was what I eventually used.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by adding an AJAX Timer from the Toolbox into the `UpdatePanel` and using it's `OnTick` property to call `RefreshButton_Click`

Followed the instructions [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx)